# How do I use Leibniz formula to solve this difficult equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there exists a $y$ such that $$y \equiv \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2/2}$$.

Prove that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + (n+1)y = 0$$

I'm not sure where to start as Leibniz formula require at least 2 functions to begin with. There are no clear two functions in this problem.

My thought process:

1. I could possibly factor out the y in all 3 terms, but this will make the derivatives invalid, wouldn't it?
2. So since approach 1 wouldn't work, I could try integrating the whole equation, but I wouldn't get an exponential somewhere.
3. I can try to sub in y into the equation, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this by induction. A simple calculation will verify whether the statement is true for $n = 0$. Assume it holds for $n$ and differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to show the identify holds for $n+1$, using the Leibniz rule to differentiate the second term on the left hand side.

Comment: Could you elaborate how $n=0$ results in a simple calculation?

Comment: Plug in the value of $y$ when $n = 0$, i.e. $y = e^{-x^2/2}$, into the given equation and see if it holds or not. (I assume it does.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule iteratively, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} e^{-x^2/2} &=&\frac{d}{dx} \left(x \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2/2} \right) - \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}} e^{-x^2/2} \\
&=&\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left(x \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} e^{-x^2/2} \right) - 2\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}} e^{-x^2/2} \\
& \vdots & \\
&=&\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(x \frac{d}{dx} e^{-x^2/2} \right) - n\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}} e^{-x^2/2} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Now the equation can be rewritten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left( \frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{-x^2/2} +x \frac{d}{dx} e^{-x^2/2} -ne^{-x^2/2}+(n+1)e^{-x^2/2} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
and it is easy to show that the content of the bracket is zero.